# Rational Functions without holes or asymptotes?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Can you please give me some examples of such functions. I hope 1/2 us not one of this category of functions. Please give non obvious examples. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could argue that $f(x)=1/2$ is indeed such a function, but it is a very boring example.

Comment: yeah its very boring example. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examples of rational functions without holes and  asymptotes are $$f(x)=\frac {1+x^4}{1+x^2}$$ or $$ g( x)=\frac {x^5}{4+x^2}$$

Comment: Thanks Mohammad!

Comment: What are the conditions that we should mind before creating such a functions?

Comment: We want the denominator be always positive or always negative and the degree of the numerator at least $2$ more than the degree of the denominator.

Comment: Oh that's so simple. Sorry for asking a stupid question. ;) Actually I resumed math after a long time. lol

Answer (score 3):

Is $\dfrac{x^4}{x^2+1}$ too obvious?

Comment: I don't see how this can't be exactly what the asker wanted. +1

Comment: Me neither. Let us see what the OP has to say about this.